# Apply sound effects on a video file

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-audiomanager, xuggler

I am a little miss guided here and it seems i am totally lost. I am developing an android app and its core idea is to develop a video recorder and video player that applies some sound effects on the voice of the people or any sound that it records. Sound effect means that if i make a video of a person who is giving some speech then there should be no effect on video but his/her voice should appear like voice in talking tom cat app. I hope you understand the idea. Similar app is Helium Booth you can check it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nID3zci9qU). I am trying to use libraries like libSonic, libpd and tried to use XUGGLE too.
Read somewhere that Xuggle is not really developed for mobile devices so left it. Now what i want is that it should apply this effect on voice on the run time i.e while recording the pitch of the sound should be alterd and saved immediately. And what i am getting with these libraries is that i can apply sound effect after video is recorded. So it means i need to rip the audio from the video and then apply the change in pitch and frequency and again concatenate this audio file with the old video file. And i have no idea how to do it.
Please show me the right approach and tools if possible.

Regards

Comment: This highly depends on the video codec, although the audio is usually a separate channel in all video codecs I know about.

Comment: so can i change sound on run time or have to fetch audio from video and apply changes?

Comment: You can do as you please.

Comment: can you tell me what approach should i user to apply sound effects on run time while recording the video?

Comment: I've never developed video software, sorry, but I've used video editors a lot and I know you can do that. Sorry I can't be of more help...

Comment: @TalhaMalik Have you made this application.?